# finding intersection of intervals in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes

```
df_a=

     Start Stop Value
    0  0     100  0.0
    1  101   200  1.0
    2  201  1000  0.0

df_b=
       Start Stop Value
    0  0     50 0.0
    1  51   300 1.0
    2  301 1000  0.0
```

I would like to generate a `DataFrame` which contains the intervals as identified by `Start` and `Stop`, where Value was the same in `df_a` and df_b. For each interval I would like to store: if `Value` was the same, and which was the value in `df_a` and `df_b`.
Desired output:

```
df_out=
  Start Stop SameValue Value_dfA Value_dfB
      0    50    1          0       0
      51   100   0          0       1
      101  200   1          1       1
      201  300   0          0       1
    [...]
```

Comment: How did you get a start of `102`?

Comment: It's the next value after 101 (upper bound of previous interval).

Comment: Isn't the upper bound only `100` for the previous interval, given the 2 `df_a` and `df_b`.

Comment: No, because of [101, 200] & [51,300], resulting in [51,101] | [102,200] | [201,300].

Comment: Perhaps `pandas.merge_asof` could be of interest for this question? (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html).

Comment: I am sorry there was one clear typo  i have edited

Comment: @Guybrush, that doesn't make sense but don't worry the OP has clarified.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best way to do this but you can `reindex`, `join`,  `groupby` and `agg` to get your intervals, e.g.:

Expand each `df` so that the index is every single value of the range (`Start` to `Stop`) using `reindex()` and `pad`ding the values:

```
In []:
df_a_expanded = df_a.set_index('Start').reindex(range(max(df_a['Stop'])+1)).fillna(method='pad')
df_a_expanded

Out[]:
         Stop  Value
Start               
0       100.0    0.0
1       100.0    0.0
2       100.0    0.0
3       100.0    0.0
4       100.0    0.0
...
997    1000.0    0.0
998    1000.0    0.0
999    1000.0    0.0
1000   1000.0    0.0

[1001 rows x 2 columns]

In []:
df_b_expanded = df_b.set_index('Start').reindex(range(max(df_b['Stop'])+1)).fillna(method='pad')
```

Join the two expanded `dfs`:

```
In []:
df = df_a_expanded.join(df_b_expanded, lsuffix='_dfA', rsuffix='_dfB').reset_index()
df

Out[]:
      Start  Stop_dfA  Value_dfA  Stop_dfB  Value_dfB
0         0     100.0        0.0      50.0        0.0
1         1     100.0        0.0      50.0        0.0
2         2     100.0        0.0      50.0        0.0
3         3     100.0        0.0      50.0        0.0
4         4     100.0        0.0      50.0        0.0
...
```

Note: you can ignore the `Stop` columns and could have dropped them in the previous step.

There is no standard way to `groupby` only consecutive values (à la `itertools.groupby`), so resorting to a `cumsum()` hack:

```
In []:
groups = (df[['Value_dfA', 'Value_dfB']] != df[['Value_dfA', 'Value_dfB']].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
g = df.groupby([groups, 'Value_dfA', 'Value_dfB'], as_index=False)
```

Now you can get the result you want by aggregating the group with `min`, `max`:

```
In []:
df_out = g['Start'].agg({'Start': 'min', 'Stop': 'max'})
df_out

Out[]:
   Value_dfA  Value_dfB  Start  Stop
0        0.0        0.0      0    50
1        0.0        1.0     51   100
2        1.0        1.0    101   200
3        0.0        1.0    201   300
4        0.0        0.0    301  1000
```

Now you just have to add the `SameValue` column and, if desired, order the columns to get the exact output you want:

```
In []:
df_out['SameValue'] = (df_out['Value_dfA'] == df_out['Value_dfB'])*1
df_out[['Start', 'Stop', 'SameValue', 'Value_dfA', 'Value_dfB']]

Out[]:
   Start  Stop  SameValue  Value_dfA  Value_dfB
0      0    50          1        0.0        0.0
1     51   100          0        0.0        1.0
2    101   200          1        1.0        1.0
3    201   300          0        0.0        1.0
4    301  1000          1        0.0        0.0
```

This assumes the ranges of the two dataframes are the same, or you will need to handle the `NaN`s you will get with the `join()`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way but not sure it is the most efficient. You have the input data:

```
import pandas as pd
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'Start': [0, 101, 201], 'Stop': [100, 200, 1000], 'Value': [0., 1., 0.]})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'Start': [0, 51, 301], 'Stop': [50, 300, 1000], 'Value': [0., 1., 0.]})
```

First I would create the columns `Start` and `Stop` of `df_out` with:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'Start': sorted(set(dfa['Start'])|set(dfb['Start'])), 
                       'Stop': sorted(set(dfa['Stop'])|set(dfb['Stop']))})
```

Then to get the value of `dfa` (and `dfb`) associated to the right range(Start,Stop) in a column named `Value_dfA` (and `Value_dfB`), I would do:

```
df_out['Value_dfA'] = df_out['Start'].apply(lambda x: dfa['Value'][dfa['Start'] <= x].iloc[-1])
df_out['Value_dfB'] = df_out['Start'].apply(lambda x: dfb['Value'][dfb['Start'] <= x].iloc[-1])
```

To get the column `SameValue`, do:

```
df_out['SameValue'] = df_out.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['Value_dfA'] == x['Value_dfB'] else 0,axis=1)
```

If it matters, you can reorder the columns with:

```
df_out = df_out[['Start', 'Stop', 'SameValue', 'Value_dfA', 'Value_dfB']]
```

Your output is then

```
   Start  Stop  SameValue  Value_dfA  Value_dfB
0      0    50          1        0.0        0.0
1     51   100          0        0.0        1.0
2    101   200          1        1.0        1.0
3    201   300          0        0.0        1.0
4    301  1000          1        0.0        0.0
```

Comment: @AChampion indeed there is a problem if you just replace 300 by 200 in `dfb['Stop']`, but then you have no value for the interval 201 to 300 in `dfb` as the next start is at 301. In this case, yes it does not work. But if the intervals are successive, then you also have to replace 301 by 201 in `dfb['Start']` and in this case, it works :)

Comment: You are right my apologies, ignore. Deleted comment.

Comment: Actually I think you were right to point out this with my answer in case someone else has data with missing intervals. I guess we can add some lines to fill the missing intervals to prevent breaks

Answer (score 1):

I have `O(nlog(n))` solution where `n` is the sum of rows of `df_a` and `df_b`. Here's how it goes:

Rename `value` column of both dataframes to `value_a` and `value_b` repsectively. Next append `df_b` to `df_a`.

```
df = df_a.append(df_b)
```

Sort the `df` with respect to `start` column.

```
df = df.sort_values('start')
```

Resulting dataframe will look like this:

```
 start  stop    value_a value_b
0   0   100     0.0      NaN
0   0   50      NaN      0.0
1   51  300     NaN      1.0
1   101 200     1.0      NaN
2   201 1000    0.0      NaN
2   301 1000    NaN      0.0
```

Forward fill the missing values:

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Compute `same_value` column:

```
df['same_value'] = df['value_a'] == df['value_b']
```

Recompute `stop` column:

```
df.stop = df.start.shift(-1)
```

You will get the dataframe you desire (except the first and last row which is pretty easy to fix):

```
 start   stop value_a value_b   same_value
0   0     0.0   0.0   NaN     False
0   0     51.0  0.0   0.0     True
1   51    101.0 0.0   1.0     False
1   101   201.0 1.0   1.0     True
2   201   301.0 0.0   1.0     False
2   301   NaN   0.0   0.0     True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer which computes the overlapping intervals really quickly (which answers the question in the title):

```
from io import StringIO    
import pandas as pd    
from ncls import NCLS    

c1 = StringIO("""Start Stop Value
0     100  0.0
101   200  1.0
201  1000  0.0""")

c2 = StringIO("""Start Stop Value
0     50 0.0
51   300 1.0
301 1000  0.0""")

df1 = pd.read_table(c1, sep="\s+")
df2 = pd.read_table(c2, sep="\s+")

ncls = NCLS(df1.Start.values, df1.Stop.values, df1.index.values)

x1, x2 = ncls.all_overlaps_both(df2.Start.values, df2.Stop.values, df2.index.values)

df1 = df1.reindex(x2).reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.reindex(x1).reset_index(drop=True)

# print(df1)
# print(df2)

df = df1.join(df2, rsuffix="2")

print(df)
#    Start  Stop  Value  Start2  Stop2  Value2
# 0      0   100    0.0       0     50     0.0
# 1      0   100    0.0      51    300     1.0
# 2    101   200    1.0      51    300     1.0
# 3    201  1000    0.0      51    300     1.0
# 4    201  1000    0.0     301   1000     0.0
```

With this final df it should be simple to get to the result you need (but it is left as an exercise for the reader).

See [NCLS](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/ncls) for the interval overlap data structure.